# CSS не работает @media

Tags: css, webkit, media

Пытаюсь подправить шаблон под мобильники, но почему-то не работает @madia

Работает

```
.video-text p{
    color: blue;
}
```

НЕ работает

```
@madia screen and (max-width: 768px) {
.video-text p{
    color: green;
    font-size: 24px;
}
}
```

Подскажите, пожалуйста, может быть это конфликт какой-то? Тут много чего сделано через @-webkit. (В верстке не силен)

Comment: @mAdia - ?? серьёзно?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
@media screen and (max-width: 768px) {
  .video-text p {
      color: green;
      font-size: 24px;
  }
}
```